# Why is the wrong method called: Strange inheritance behaviour

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

So this question is about inheritance and method overriding.
Specifically: the case when a child class has a same-name method as the parent, but with a different signature, like:

```
class A has methodX(String arg)
class B extends A has methodX(int arg)
```

In normal cases the correct method will be called based on the argument.

But in the following code I've encountered some strange behavior which I can't really explain:

```
static class A {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("m1.A");
    }
    public void method4(A arg) {        //Original method4
        System.out.println("m4.A");
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("m1.B");
    }
}

static class C extends B {
    public void method4(A arg) {        //Override method4 from Class A
        System.out.println("m4.C");
    }
}

static class E extends C {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("m1.E");
    }
    public void method4(E arg) {        //NO OVERRIDE: Same name, but different method4 than in class A or C
        System.out.println("m4.E");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    A va = new A();
    B vb = new B();
    C vc = new C();
    E ve = new E();

    //At this point everything is fine
    ve.method4(ve);  //Calls method4 from class E based on parameter type - CORRECT
    ve.method4(va);  //Calls method4 from class C based on parameter type - CORRECT

    //After this code strange things happen
    vc = new E();
    vb = vc;

    vb.method1();    //Output: m1.E; method1 from class E is called - CORRECT
    vb.method4(vb);  //Output: m4.C; method4 from class C is called - why?

    vc.method1();    //Output: m1.E; method1 from class E is called - CORRECT
    vc.method4(vc);  //Output: m4.C; method4 from class C is called - why?
    vc.method4(ve);  //Output: m4.C; method4 from class C is called - why?

}
```

So the output of the programm above is:

```
m4.E
m4.C

m1.E
m4.C  //why? Expected: m4.E

m1.E
m4.C  //why? Expected: m4.E
m4.C  //why? Expected: m4.E
```

The behaviour of

```
vb and vc
```

is what i cannot understand. Any ideas?

Comment: It would really help if you could explain what you *expected* to happen.

Comment: And you talk about a method accepting an `int` early on, but none of your methods do...

Comment: You could also have made your example significantly simpler - it's not clear why you need 5 classes in order to demonstrate this, or why any of them need to be nested in a class you haven't posted...

Comment: Added expected results. The example with an int was just for demonstrating purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you *expected* `m4.E` to be printed. But don't forget that *overload* resolution is performed at compile-time, not at execution time.

Neither `C` nor `B` have a `method4(E)` method available, so the compiler resolves the calls to the `method4(A)` method... which *isn't* overridden by `E`. All the calls you have `m4.C // why?` in the question are calls to a method with signature `method4(A)`, called on an instance of `E`. Now `E` doesn't override `method4(A)`, so it's left with the implementation in `C`, which prints `m4.C`.

Nothing strange going on here at all.

Comment: I was expecting m4.E, bu I guess you meant it. My question is basically this:
after 
    vc = new E();
Why isn't vc behaving like the class E?

Comment: @user2313491: Fixed that. But again, overload resolution is performed at *compile-time*, and the compile-time type of the `vc` variable is still `C`, so the compiler isn't going to know about any method signatures declared by `E`. Only *overriding* is performed at execution time - that's the choice of which *implementation* of the method signature is used, not the method signature itself.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly - at compile time the compiler "searches" for a method4(E) in B/C, doesn't find one, resolves to method4(A). At execution time the overriding occurs, so if the class E did override the method4(A) it would choose the latter implementation.

Comment: @user2313491: Well, at compile-time the compiler looks for all method declarations are compatible - based only on compile-time types - with the method call `method4(vc)` (or whatever). It picks the best one, and then the implementation is picked at execution time.

Comment: Now I see my mistake - I assumed things that became only true on execution time, i.e. that at vc = new E() the methods from class E would be looked up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't overridden `method4` between class `C` and class `E`: they have different signatures.

With `method1`, it takes no arguments, so the subclass is overriding the existing method. But the compiler sees

```
public void method4(E arg);
```

and

```
public void method4(C arg);
```

as entirely different (as different as if they'd got different names).

You should try annotating your methods in the subclasses with `@Override`. You'll find it'll allow it on `method1` and complain on `method4`.

For the last couple of lines, the compiler will

1. Look up `method4` in class `C`, since `vc` has a declared type of `C`.
2. Find the `method4` that fits, and see that takes an argument of a `A`.

At runtime, the JVM will then

3. See if the method chosen by the compiler is overridden in a subclass for the actual type of `vc`.
4. Discover that this method isn't overridden, and so use the method from `C`.

I think the confusion is coming from having these three lines in close succession:

```
C vc = new C();
// ...
vc = new E();
// ...
vc.method4(vc);  //Output: m4.C; method4 from class C is called - why?
```

You and I can see that the actual type of `vc` is going to be `E`, because you've just created a `new E()` and assigned it to `vc`. But the compiler can't in general be expected to make this kind of inference: in a real application, the code might have been much more complicated, and not something that could be resolved to an actual type with any certainty at compile time. The middle line might have been

```
vc = runningOnAThursday ? new E() : new C();
```

All the compiler can do is to look at the *declared* type, which is `C`. It's only at runtime that checks about *actual* types (and, hence, about overridden methods) can be performed.

Comment: Exactly! But if you look at the code again you will find my comment about this! It is the point of the question!

Comment: @user2313491 Updated answer to explain further.

Comment: I see you point now, it's almost the same explanation as from Jon Skeet the latter being more thorough. 
My mistake was assuming that after vc = new E() the compiler would look up methods from the type E

Comment: @Kezaer I've updated the answer with something that I think will help to explain where the confusion came in and why this is a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

You sorta lost me with the 4 methods between 5 classes, but I can guess that you expected the method that takes the **actual type** of the instance to be called.

However, that's not a valid assumption, as Java can only call the method with the **most specific known type** of the Object.

Here is a much simpler example that demonstrates what I'm talking about:

```
public class Test {

    public static void method(String obj){
        System.out.println("String");
    }

    public static void method(Object obj){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }


    public static void main(String... args){
        Object string = "testing";
        method(string);
    }
}
```

Note that this code calls the method(Object) function, even though the actual type of the string variable is a String. This is because the most specific type that Java knows the string variable is, is Object, not String.